# Which material enclosure to avoid impeding signal of Bluetooth and wifi?

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, bluetooth-low-energy, enclosure, esp32

I’m making an enclosure for:

https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/ESP32-PICO-KIT/1904-1030-ND

I read that Bluetooth signal can be impeded by 37% by a plastic case. If that is so, then how does one design a case to protect the esp32 from dust , water , etc, without impeding the signal?

Comment: Wherever you've read that 37%, it's utter nonsense, or utterly taken out of context. That's not how any of this even remotely works. Any material interacts with electromagnetic waves, but most carbohydrate polymers are mostly low-loss for "normal" thicknesses.

Comment: @MarcusMüller There aren't many carbohydrate polymers, and few used for enclosures. Examples would be cellulose, wood etc. Perhaps you're thinking of hydrocarbon polymers.

Comment: @Neil_UK haha, you're right! Brain stuck between a coffee mug and a heap of DSP code.

Comment: You can get ESP modules that havr U.FL jacks for an external antenna.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I’m a bit confused. Does that mean as long as my enclosure wall is thin ABS, I shouldn’t worry?

Comment: @KaizerSozay the \$\epsilon\$ of ABS is sufficiently close to that of air that influence will be hard to measure.

Comment: @MarcusMüller so guessing it doesn’t matter then?

Comment: hm, how many times do you want me to repeat what I already wrote?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am a robot, dude. My responses are limited. You must provide the right input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverted F antenna on many ESP modules is tuned for the band used by the module and can be de-tuned by other material in close proximity. space the antenna away from the material to avoid this effect. 10mm is probably enough.

Comment: So the gap between the enclosure wall and the antenna should be  at least 10mm ? Can I ask what if the antenna has been slightly dented during shipping? Does it matter?

Comment: Ok, I see in the photo the sheet metal antenna. that's going to work better than a printed antenna.  but yeah, they're more fragile.  all dents will hurt performance, small dents less than big dents.